# how to check why an API fill a variable

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have been trying to get the data from this API to display in the console based off of the name of the college I input, but variables aren't working and aren't getting any data from the API to store.

What I have so far:

```js
// Function to retrieve school information
function getSchoolInformation() {
  var schoolName = document.getElementById("schoolName").value;
  fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-10/tuition_cost.csv')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(csvData => {
      var schoolInfo = findSchoolInformation(schoolName, csvData);
      displaySchoolInformation(schoolInfo);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

// Function to find school information based on school name
function findSchoolInformation(schoolName, csvData) {
  var parsedData = Papa.parse(csvData, {
    header: true,
    skipEmptyLines: true
  }).data;
  var schoolInfo = [];

  parsedData.forEach(function(row) {
    var collegeName = row["INSTNM"];
    var degreeLength = row["CURROPER"];
    var tuitionCost = row["TUITIONFEE_IN"];

    if (collegeName && collegeName.toLowerCase() === schoolName.toLowerCase()) {
      collegeName = collegeName.toLowerCase();
      degreeLength = parseInt(degreeLength);
      tuitionCost = parseFloat(tuitionCost);

      if (!isNaN(degreeLength) && !isNaN(tuitionCost)) {
        schoolInfo.push({
          collegeName: collegeName,
          degreeLength: degreeLength,
          tuitionCost: tuitionCost
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return schoolInfo;
}

// Function to display school information in the console
function displaySchoolInformation(schoolInfo) {
  for (var i = 0; i < schoolInfo.length; i++) { //never runs
    var collegeName = schoolInfo[i].collegeName;
    var degreeLength = schoolInfo[i].degreeLength;
    var tuitionCost = schoolInfo[i].tuitionCost;

    console.log("College Name: " + collegeName);
    console.log("Degree Length: " + degreeLength);
    console.log("Tuition Cost: $" + tuitionCost.toFixed(2));
    console.log("------------------------------");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<label for="schoolName">Enter School Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="schoolName" />
<button onclick="getSchoolInformation()">Get Information</button>
```

I have tried so many variations of my code but none seem to work and it is slowly turning more into spaghetti code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Which variables aren't working? Have you tried `console.log(csvData)` to make sure you're getting the response?

Comment: The column names you access with `row["INSTNM"]`, `row["CURROPER"]` and `row["TUITIONFEE_IN"]` don't exist in that CSV file. The header line is `name,state,state_code,type,degree_length,room_and_board,in_state_tuition,in_state_total,out_of_state_tuition,out_of_state_total`

Comment: So you want `row.name`,  `row.degree_length`, and `row.in_state_tuition`.

Answer (score 0):

Use names returned: comment with all the names of returned.

Note use of dot notation instead of array notation for the objects.

Suggest you might not return the lower case re: `collegeName = collegeName.toLowerCase();` on the name.

```js
// Function to retrieve school information
function getSchoolInformation() {
  let schoolName = document.getElementById("schoolName").value;
  console.log("trying:", schoolName);
  fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-10/tuition_cost.csv')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((csvData) => {
      //console.log('CSV:', csvData);
      let schoolInfo = findSchoolInformation(schoolName, csvData);
      displaySchoolInformation(schoolInfo);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

// Function to find school information based on school name
function findSchoolInformation(schoolName, csvData) {
  let parsedData = Papa.parse(csvData, {
    header: true,
    skipEmptyLines: true
  }).data;
  let schoolInfo = [];
  //console.log('pd:', parsedData[0]);
  parsedData.forEach(function(row) {
    //  name,state,state_code,type,degree_length,room_and_board,in_state_tuition,in_state_total,out_of_state_tuition,out_of_state_total
    //let collegeName = row["name"];
    //let degreeLength = row["degree_length"];
    //let tuitionCost = row["in_state_tuition"];
    // suggest to use dot notation
    let collegeName = row.name;
    let degreeLength = row.degree_length;
    let tuitionCost = row.in_state_tuition;

    if (collegeName && collegeName.toLowerCase() === schoolName.toLowerCase()) {
      collegeName = collegeName.toLowerCase();
      degreeLength = parseInt(degreeLength);
      tuitionCost = parseFloat(tuitionCost);
      //console.log(collegeName, degreeLength, tuitionCost)
      if (!isNaN(degreeLength) && !isNaN(tuitionCost)) {
        schoolInfo.push({
          collegeName: collegeName,
          degreeLength: degreeLength,
          tuitionCost: tuitionCost
        });
      }
    }
  });
  console.log('SI:', schoolInfo);
  return schoolInfo;
}

// Function to display school information in the console
function displaySchoolInformation(schoolInfo) {
  for (var i = 0; i < schoolInfo.length; i++) { //never runs
    let collegeName = schoolInfo[i].collegeName;
    let degreeLength = schoolInfo[i].degreeLength;
    let tuitionCost = schoolInfo[i].tuitionCost;

    console.log("College Name: " + collegeName);
    console.log("Degree Length: " + degreeLength);
    console.log("Tuition Cost: $" + tuitionCost.toFixed(2));
    console.log("------------------------------");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

<label for="schoolName">Enter School Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="schoolName" value="Duke University" />
<button onclick="getSchoolInformation()">Get Information</button>
```